# Can't set button width in iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I need two buttons with equal width like in following screen. But I can't set its width(half of `superview` width). Should I set an image to button or how to set width with half of screen size?

**Image :**

[image: Image here]

Comment: how are you setting and what are you trying ? are you setting from code or using autolayout ?

Comment: i added constraints to left and bottom with height = 60, but can't set the width

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add constraint to both buttons to be equal width to superview with a multiplier of 1:2 and then snap both to bottom and left button to left and right button to right.

[image]

Comment: You can add NSLayoutConstraint programmatically or in storyboard, I recommend storyboard though.

Comment: @Arbitur, what is the need of the multiplier..? This also works by only setting the equal widths constraint.

Comment: @ArpitDhamane Multiplier is if setting width equal to superview, first that came to mind :P, otherwise setting button width equal to eachother and setting constraint between them to 0 works aswell.

Answer (score 0):

If you use autoLayout, best way is to make both button having a constraint of equal width